# The file ChromeDriver does not exist when running on Docker

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run Selenium on Docker using Azure Function in C#. I've installed Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver nuget packages. In docker file I've also put code for installing Chrome driver, but when I try to create ChromeDriver in code, I get exception that chromedriver can't be found.

When I list all files in directory, I can see that there is chromedriver.exe file listed:
[image]

but when I try to create a new Chrome driver using this line:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

I get the following exception:

> The file /home/site/wwwroot/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/chromedriver does
> not exist. The driver can be downloaded at
> http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

Why chromedriver.exe file is not recognized? When I run the same code without Docker, everything works fine.

Comment: In the screenshot that you posted, is that on your machine or a list of files while deployed via Docker? That could make a big difference. You might think the file is there, but it isn't.

Comment: This is a list of files when app is deployed via Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Add the absolute path of chromedriver.exe to container PATH environment variable

Comment: Not sure how to add absolute path when running on Docker? I’ve tried to set it like this:
ENV PATH="home/site/wwwroot/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/chromedriver:${PATH}" but with  no luck..

Comment: Slash before home: /home/…

Comment: It expects chromedriver, but you have chromedriver.exe

Comment: I've changed the path when creating ChromeDriver. Now it takes path where chromedriver is (not the exe version) but now I get the following error: System.Diagnostics.Process: No such file or directory. What could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Typically Windows executables end with `.exe` while Linux executables have no file extension. A file being executable on Linux is a consequence of file permissions rather than some naming convention.

The file path in the exception message uses forward-slashes `/` as file path delimiters rather than back slashes `\` leading me to believe you have downloaded a Windows-compatible ChromeDriver which you are attempting to run on a Linux machine.

**Solution**: download the Linux driver instead when deployed via Docker.

Comment: Thank you! I've downloaded Linux version and it can be found using "/usr/local/bin" path. When listing files, I can see now that there is /usr/local/bin/chromedriver. I'm using this path for creating ChromeDriver but now I get the following exception: "System.Diagnostics.Process: No such file or directory". What could cause this error?

Comment: Permissions? Make sure that file has execute permissions.

Comment: How can I check those permissions when working with Linux docker? Where can I see those files and their permissions?

Comment: @MonnNin: you will need to post a new question.

Comment: I've checked them now, everything seems OK. Not sure why "System.Diagnostics.Process: No such file or directory" occurs.